# How to pass raw html to Play framework view?

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to pass a simple URL to a view within a play framework app, however when passed as a string, the `&` in the url is changed to `&amp;` which causes the URL to not work.

If I change the argument to Html, i.e `@(url: Srting)` to `@(url: Html)`, then I get an error when I try to pass the url as string to `view.render()` method.

How can I convert the url into Html and pass it as that?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

To prevent the default escaping that happens for dynamic content on views you need to wrap the `String` with `@Html(String)` function:

View:

```
@(url: String)
<div class="myLink">
   Go to: @Html(url) <br>
   not to: @url
</div>
```

Controller:

```
public static Result displayLink(){
   return ok(view.render("<a href='http://stackoverflow.com/'>Stack Overflow</a>"));
}
```

See [The template engine](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.4/JavaTemplates) page on the documentation for more info (specifically the "Escaping" section at the very bottom).

Comment: Where do I need to put this annotation? Within the controller?

Comment: E.g right now in my controller I'm doing: `String url = SomeModel.getUrl(); return ok( myView.render( url) );`. Where should I put the `@html()` annotation?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to render HTML content instead of displaying it as raw text, return the content `.as("text/html")`. Example:

```
WS.url("http://www.stackoverflow.com").get().map(resp => Ok(resp.body).as("text/html"))
```