# Play! 2.3.1 - displaying HTML source code instead of page

Tags: java, html, scala, playframework-2.0

My Application class looks like this:

```
public class Application extends Controller {

public static Result index() {
    return ok(index.render("<p>This is a paragraph</p>"));
}
```

and my `index.scala.html` file looks like:

```
@(htmlcode: String)

@main("Example") {
    @htmlcode
}
```

and my `main.scala.html` file is fairly simple, with the standard !DOCTYPE declaration, html, head, body tags, etc.

```
...
<body>@content</body>
...
```

But when I run my application, the index page displays the source code `<p>This is a paragraph</p>` instead of just `This is a paragraph`. The source file looks like

```
...
<body>
&lt;p&gt;This is a paragraph&lt;/p&gt;
</body>
...
```

How would I have the page render the code instead of just displaying it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is simply converting/protecting the values you are giving it. All the HTML markup should be done in the template (scala.html) file and not in the controller.

BTW this question comes pretty closes to this other question : [How to pass raw html to Play framework view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14743199/how-to-pass-raw-html-to-play-framework-view)

Comment: So there is no way a controller can write the HTML code? I'm working with the Tumblr API and retrieving blog post information, and the API returns each post in HTML form in a Java String, and I'd like to display on a page.

Comment: Ah, I see your follow-up. Thank you very much.

Comment: @ypan Be very careful rendering raw HTML from third-party APIs. You open yourself to script injection attacks.

Comment: @acjay What does that mean? Where can I read more about this?

Comment: @ypan Google cross-site scripting (XSS).

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the Html() function

```
@main("Example") {
@Html(htmlcode)
}
```